# What kind of data storage uses Sparkfun's phant?

Tags: arduino

What kind of data storage uses [Sparkfun's phant](https://github.com/sparkfun/phant)? Do they use a kind of a key-value or relational data store in background or a document-based one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess i found an answer for this now on my own. According to [www.prokarma.com's blog](https://www.prokarma.com/blog/2014/09/03/phant-iot-devices-getting-your-iot-data-cloud) they use

> a repository for storing key value pairs being pushed from devices
>   connected to the internet.